# Prove that there exists at least one integer $k$ for every odd $n$ such that $x^2+x-2k$ is irreducible modulo $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, congruences

I've tried several approaches, but none seem to get me any closer, and a solution is not available. Please help.

Comment: What were those tries ? Why are you not showing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say, no such $k$, exists.

So there exists numbers $x_1,x_2\dots ,x_{n} \in \{0,1,2,3...n\}$, such that

$x_1^2+x_1=0$ **(mod n)**

$x_2^2+x_2=2$ **(mod n)**

$x_3^2+x_3=4$ **(mod n)** 
.

.

.

.
$x_{n}^2+x_{n}=2(n-1)$ **(mod n)**

Claim, $x_1,x_2 \dots ,x_{n}$, are all distinct, else if say $x_i=x_j$, then subtract the corresponding two equation, we will have $n|2(i-j)$, which is not possible as $n$ is odd and $|i-j|<n$, hence $\{x_1,x_2 \dots ,x_{n}\}$ is an enumeration of $\{0,1,2,3,\dots ,n-1\}$

So there exists $p,q \in \{1,2,3,\dots ,n\}$ such that $x_p=0$ and $x_q=n-1$, but $0^2+0=(n-1)^2+(n-1)$ **(mod n)** , hence a condradiction.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand the last part. How'd you get that?

Comment: $(n-1)^2+(n-1)=n^2-2n+1+n-1=n^2-n$ which leaves a remainder 0 when divided by $n$,

So $x_p^2+x_p$ and $x_q^2+x_q$ leave the same remainder when divided by $n$ but they are supposed to leave two distinct remainders, hence a contradiction

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest way to solve this problem is to simply count the number of distinct polynomials of that form that factor, and see that it is less than $n$. Thus some polynomials of that form do not factor.

For every odd n, 2 is a unit modulo $n$. Thus it is sufficient to show that some $x^2+x+i$ is irreducible modulo $n$ for $i$ ranging from $0$ to $n-1$.

Suppose that all $n$ such (distinct) polynomials factored into $(x-a_i)(x-b_i)$ where $i$ ranges from $0$ to $n-1$. Then by expanding, we get $x^2+x+i = x^2 + (-a_i-b_i)x + a_ib_i$. In particular, $-a_i-b_i = 1$. Since each $b_i$ is fixed with respect to $a_i$, there can only be $n$ such pairs, corresponding to $(x-a_i)(x+a_i+1)$, where $a_i$ ranges from 1 to $n$. However, the polynomials given by $a_i = 0$ and $a_i = -1$ are both the same polynomial: $(x-0)(x+1)$. In fact, we can group each $m, -m+1$ pair in a like manner to find that the number of distinct polynomials of the form $x^2+x+i$ that factor is $(n+1)/2$. It is then easy to see that the number of distinct polynomials that do not factor is $(n-1)/2$. Since this is less than $n$, there are some polynomials that do not factor.

Comment: To summarize, the number of factorable polynomials of this form $(x-a)(x-b)$ can be indexed by $(x-i)(x+i+1)$, where $i$ ranges from 0 to $n-1$. Then it is easy to see that the number of distinct such polynomials is simply the number of distinct pairs $i, -i-1$. There is at least one such pair, $0, -1$, so there are at most $n-1$ factorable polynomials of that form, and equivalently, at least $1$ non-factorable (irreducible) polynomial of that form.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some helpful facts:

1. It is sufficient to prove the property when $n$ is an odd prime.
2. A quadratic polynomial over a field is reducible exactly if it has a root.
3. The polynomials for different $k$ (modulo $n$) cannot have roots in common.
4. The polynomial for $k=0$ has two *different* roots.